# How to get the top 1% of soloists calculated by the total number of concerts performed

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working on this sql challenge, but I don't know if the way to get *the top 1% of soloists calculated by the total number of concerts performed.* is correct. Please help me, thank you. Below are the challenge and my code.

**1. Orchestra Celebration**

The New York Philharmonic is one of America's largest orchestras. In honor of its many famous musicians, the director is planning a special event. She wants to hold a concert to celebrate the top soloists from its history. You have been asked to determine which soloists should receive recognition.The director has given you the following requirements:

- The results should only include the top 1% of soloists calculated by
  the total number of concerts performed.
- Limit your results to entries where the orchestra is 'New York
  Philharmonic' and the event type is 'Subscription Season'.  Soloist
  performances in other orchestras or event types should not count
  towards the calculation of the top soloists.
- The director is only interested in individual soloists. You will need
  to exclude all of the following soloists: 'Chorus', 'No Soloist', 'New York Choral Artists', and 'Schola Cantorum of NY'. You should
  also exclude any soloist with 'choir' in the name.

Your result should contain the following columns. It should meet all requirements as described.

**column    requirements**

1. ***name***  The name of the soloist, with the first name followed by the last name (e.g., Jane Smith). Please note that in the soloists table, names are in reverse order (last name, first name).
2. ***first_date*** The first date the soloist ever performed with the orchestra, in the format '01 Jan 2015' (i.e., month as an integer, short month name, and year as an integer).
3. ***last_date*** The last date the soloist ever performed with the orchestra, in the format '01 Jan 2015' (i.e., month as an integer, short month name, and year as an integer).
4. ***total_concerts*** The total number of concerts the soloist performed.

Order your results by the total number of concerts performed in descending order, and then by soloist name in alphabetical order. The data you will need is available in the two tables detailed in the schema below.
[This is a picture of the schema](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18AMkGfwbgr-ujCCtgkaAaFsIpcmEJN4X?usp=sharing)
This is the [dataset](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18AMkGfwbgr-ujCCtgkaAaFsIpcmEJN4X?usp=sharing)

Below is my code and I don't know where I'm wrong, please help me, thank you all in advance

```
SELECT 
    concat(substring(soloist_name from position(',' in soloist_name)+1 for char_length(soloist_name)),
           ' ', 
           substring(soloist_name from 0 for position(',' in soloist_name))) as name,
    To_char(min(date)::date, 'DD Mon YYYY') as first_date,
    To_char(max(date)::date, 'DD Mon YYYY') as last_date,
    count(concertnumber) as total_concerts
     
FROM soloists join concerts using (id)
WHERE 
    orchestra LIKE 'New York Philharmonic' 
    and eventtype LIKE 'Subscription Season' 
    and soloist_name NOT IN ('Chorus', 
                             'No Soloist', 
                             'New York Choral Artists', 
                             'Schola Cantorum of NY')
    and soloist_name NOT LIKE ('%Choir%')
  
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY total_concerts desc, name
limit 29
```

This is how I get 1% of the soloists (29 out of 2887), and this is where I think I am wrong, but don't know how to fix.

Comment: "1%" sounds like you need the `ntile` window function.

Comment: because of a possible tie, the limit of 29 makes no sense... You must use appropriate functions like RANK that jumps the ex aequo or DENSE_RANK that does not, and filter with a subquery.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe how?

Comment: both answers thanh Pham and sql pro gives almost same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution that worked for me, I've used a subquery for the 1% limit because I don't like hardcoding the limit.

```sql
%%sql
postgresql:///orchestra
    
SELECT
    CONCAT(TRIM(BOTH FROM SUBSTRING(s.soloist_name, STRPOS(s.soloist_name,',') + 2)),' ',TRIM(BOTH FROM SUBSTRING(s.soloist_name,0,STRPOS(s.soloist_name,',')))) AS name,
    TO_CHAR(MIN(c.date)::date,'DD Mon YYYY') AS first_date,
    TO_CHAR(MAX(c.date)::date,'DD Mon YYYY') AS last_date,
    COUNT(s.id) AS total_concerts
FROM
    soloists s
JOIN
    concerts c
ON
    s.id = c.id
WHERE
    c.orchestra = 'New York Philharmonic'
AND
    c.eventtype = 'Subscription Season'
AND
    s.soloist_name NOT IN ('Chorus','No Soloist','New York Choral Artists','Schola Cantorum of NY')
AND
    LOWER(s.soloist_name) NOT LIKE '%choir%'
GROUP BY
    s.soloist_name
ORDER BY
    total_concerts DESC,
    name ASC
LIMIT(
    SELECT(
        COUNT(name)* 0.01)::integer
        FROM(SELECT
                s.soloist_name AS name,
                COUNT(s.id) AS total_concerts
             FROM
                soloists s
             JOIN
                concerts c
             ON
                s.id = c.id
             WHERE
                c.orchestra = 'New York Philharmonic'
             AND
                c.eventtype = 'Subscription Season'
             AND
                s.soloist_name NOT IN ('Chorus','No Soloist','New York Choral Artists','Schola Cantorum of NY')
             AND
                LOWER(s.soloist_name) NOT LIKE '%choir%'
             GROUP BY
                s.soloist_name) AS s);
```

Let me know if it worked for you

Comment: I think there are 2 things that could be improved here. First, the requirement states   **The first date the soloist ever performed with the orchestra, in the format '01 Jan 2015' (i.e., month as an integer, short month name, and year as an integer**, so the code should be `'MM Mon yyyy'` instead of `'dd Mon yyyy'`. Second, name should be added to`order by total_concerts desc, name`.After everything, Datacamp still doesn't accept it. I'm still working on it. @Gonzalo

Comment: I just updated it. Let me know if it worked for you

Comment: It worked finally.  I would've got the correct solution sooner, if it wasn't for the misleading instruction **The first date the soloist ever performed with the orchestra, in the format '01 Jan 2015' (i.e., `month` as an integer, short `month` name, and year as an integer**. Thank you very much for helping me out.

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark my answer as the correct solution

Comment: I did already, but I need 15 reputation to cast a vote. I'll get enough soon. Thank you.

Comment: Ok! Next one is a little easier

Comment: Agree, but I'm quite confused at this **Keywords of the article. Multiple keywords will be seperated with a dash (-)** do I need to do anything about this? as I see it's already done.

Comment: In that one, I think you just have to replace NULL values with 'Unknown'. I still didn't solve it

Answer (score 0):

As an example with the RANK windowing function :

```
WITH 
T AS
(
SELECT 
    concat(substring(soloist_name from position(',' in soloist_name)+1 for char_length(soloist_name)),
           ' ', 
           substring(soloist_name from 0 for position(',' in soloist_name))) as name,
    To_char(min(date)::date, 'DD Mon YYYY') as first_date,
    To_char(max(date)::date, 'DD Mon YYYY') as last_date,
    sum(concertnumber) as total_concerts,
    RANK() OVER(ORDER BY sum(concertnumber) DESC) AS RANK_SOLOIST,
    COUNT(*) AS NUMBER
     
FROM soloists join concerts using (id)
WHERE 
    orchestra LIKE 'New York Philharmonic' 
    and eventtype LIKE 'Subscription Season' 
    and soloist_name NOT IN ('Chorus', 
                             'No Soloist', 
                             'New York Choral Artists', 
                             'Schola Cantorum of NY')
    and soloist_name NOT LIKE ('%Choir%')
  
GROUP BY name
HAVING sum(concertnumber) <> 0
)
SELECT *
FROM   T
WHERE  RANK_SOLOIST <= NUMBER / 100.0
```

Comment: Your solution has shed light on the issue, but the checker still marks it wrong though. Do I need to group by both id and name?

Comment: can you bring us the DDL of the tables (CREATE TABLE ...) ? To help to fix the trouble ???

Comment: I already attached the picture of a table schema in my question above. That's all I have. This sql case study on datacamp.com, so I don't have the table's DDL.

Comment: Picture as nothing to do with a SQL script. Give us as SQL script constituted of strings that are compound of letters that we can past and test into our PG solution PLEASE

Comment: I hope this is what you meant %%sql
postgresql:///orchestra

Comment: Additionally, when I run your solution, the checker says "AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all' " which I have no idea what it means

Comment: Hello im interested in this solution as well! any progress so far?

Comment: I ran the above solution but did not get the attribute error, instead I got 2 rows and 
name first_date last_date total_concerts rank_soloist number
Glenn Dicterow 16 Oct 1980 25 Jan 2014 4761821 1 277
Philip Smith 08 Nov 1979 17 Dec 2011 3598870 2 212

Comment: @thanh_pham... no we need a complete SQL script with the DDL command like CREATE TABLE soloists... CREATE TABLE concert... and as possible some INSERTs ... to populate the tables

Comment: @SQLpro only the database schema is shown though, alternatively do you like need all the records from the 2 database tables?

Comment: Not only the rows (not "records", which is an inappropiate word) but also the SQL commands to create the tables with all the constraints (Primary Key, Foreign Keys...)

Comment: @SQLpro CREATE TABLE concerts
id primary key
concertnumber numeric
date text
location text
time text
venue numeric
eventtype text
season text
programid numeric
orchestra text
-------
CREATE table soloists 
id FOREIGN KEY
entry_number numeric
soloist_instrument text
soloist_name text
soloist_roles text
programid text

Comment: @thanhpham I feel like your solution is on the right track but we can't limit 29, we sort of need to think of way to rank the soloists according to the number of total_concert

Comment: Can't you give it as a simple SQL statement to help us to past and copy to our SQL solution to test it ?

Comment: @SQLpro oh how do I do so

Comment: Use PGadmin to get the DDL of your table (or any other SQL IDE like Squirell...)

Comment: @SQLpro oh I don't have. the simple sql statement is 
CREATE TABLE concerts id primary key concertnumber numeric date text location text time text venue numeric eventtype text season text programid numeric orchestra text 

CREATE table soloists id FOREIGN KEY entry_number numeric soloist_instrument text soloist_name text soloist_roles text programid text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241376/discussion-between-fyceheist-and-sqlpro).

Comment: @fyceheist yes, I also got the same results, which are 2 rows like you shown. But this is a sql challenge of datacamp.com and when I press "check project", the checker shows that my output does not match the desired result of datacamp.com, thus I fail to complete the test. I made a slight modification at 'MM Mon YYYY' instead of 'DD Mon YYYY' to meet the format requirement, but again it doesn't meet the expected result. I also try {percentile_disc(0.99) within group (order by sum(concertnumber)) as pct99}, but it shows error. Regarding the DLL, I don't think I have access to it.@sqlpro

Comment: @fyceheist I attach a screenshot  after I adopt SQLpro's solution in the question for clarification. Sorry for any inconvenience, this is my first time on stackoverflow.

Comment: @SQLpro hello, I found the dataset, including the SQL script and the DDL command.  it's a bit late, but I hope you could give me some help. Thank you very much. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18AMkGfwbgr-ujCCtgkaAaFsIpcmEJN4X?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share my answer too. Alot of helped received from the responses by Gonzalo and SQLPro. Thx!

```
%%sql
postgresql:///orchestra
    
SELECT
    CONCAT(TRIM(BOTH FROM SUBSTRING(s.soloist_name,STRPOS(s.soloist_name,',')+2)),
           ' ',
           TRIM(BOTH FROM SUBSTRING(s.soloist_name,0,STRPOS(s.soloist_name,',')))) AS name,
    TO_CHAR(MIN(c.date) :: DATE, 'dd Mon yyyy') AS first_date,
    TO_CHAR(MAX(c.date) :: DATE, 'dd Mon yyyy') AS last_date,
    COUNT(s.id) AS total_concerts
FROM concerts AS c
JOIN soloists AS s
ON c.id = s.id
WHERE c.orchestra = 'New York Philharmonic'
    AND c.eventtype = 'Subscription Season'
    AND NOT s.soloist_name = 'Chorus'
    AND NOT s.soloist_name = 'No Soloist'
    AND NOT s.soloist_name = 'New York Choral Artists'
    AND NOT s.soloist_name = 'Schola Cantorum of NY'
    AND NOT s.soloist_name ~* 'choir'
GROUP BY s.soloist_name
ORDER BY total_concerts DESC, name ASC
LIMIT(
    SELECT CAST(COUNT(extra.name)*0.01 AS integer)
    FROM(
        SELECT 
            s.soloist_name AS name,
            COUNT(s.id) AS total_concerts
        FROM concerts AS c
        JOIN soloists AS s
        ON c.id = s.id
        WHERE c.orchestra = 'New York Philharmonic'
            AND c.eventtype = 'Subscription Season'
            AND NOT s.soloist_name = 'Chorus'
            AND NOT s.soloist_name = 'No Soloist'
            AND NOT s.soloist_name = 'New York Choral Artists'
            AND NOT s.soloist_name = 'Schola Cantorum of NY'
            AND NOT s.soloist_name ~* 'choir'
        GROUP BY s.soloist_name) AS extra);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work too. Slightly inspired by the previous answers.

```
%%sql
postgresql:///orchestra
    
SELECT
    SPLIT_PART(soloist_name,',',2) || ' ' || SPLIT_PART(soloist_name,',',1) AS name,
    TO_CHAR(MIN(date)::date, 'DD Mon YYYY') AS first_date,
    TO_CHAR(MAX(date)::date, 'DD Mon YYYY') AS last_date,
    COUNT(*) AS total_concerts
FROM concerts c
JOIN soloists s
ON c.id = s.id
WHERE c.orchestra = 'New York Philharmonic'
AND c.eventtype = 'Subscription Season'
AND s.soloist_name NOT IN ('Chorus','No Soloist','New York Choral Artists','Schola Cantorum of NY')
AND LOWER(s.soloist_name) NOT LIKE '%choir%'
GROUP BY soloist_name
ORDER BY total_concerts DESC, name ASC
LIMIT (
    SELECT COUNT(*) / 100 as onepercent
    FROM (
        SELECT s.soloist_name
        FROM concerts c
        JOIN soloists s
        ON c.id = s.id
        WHERE c.orchestra = 'New York Philharmonic'
        AND c.eventtype = 'Subscription Season'
        AND s.soloist_name NOT IN ('Chorus','No Soloist','New York Choral Artists','Schola Cantorum of NY')
        AND LOWER(s.soloist_name) NOT LIKE '%choir%'
        GROUP BY soloist_name
    ) AS s
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).